# How long is an activated charcoal filter good for after initial use?

Tags: gear, gear-care, water-purification

I have a water filtration system that uses activated coconut shell carbon as its media. The filter is listed as being able to purify up to 50 gallons, but I won't be using it for anywhere near that amount in any one use.

How long is the filter usable after initial use?  If I use it to purify a couple of gallons one weekend, then don't need it for a couple weeks, or maybe even a month, will it still be usable? Or will it need to be replaced?  Is there anything I can/should do to preserve it between uses (e.g. dry it back out somehow)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A filter like that will will be good for 50 gallons even if it's used over two years. You'll want to make sure you dry it properly between uses, and some filters have boiling instructions (esp. those with clay ceramics) when they haven't be used for an extended period of time.

Comment: How should a filter be dried?

Comment: I found this on Geiggerrig's (my filter manufacturer) site:

**In-Line Water Filter Care:** After each use fill your hydration bladder with clean water and flush the filter. After you flush the water filter, empty the water out of the filter by filling the bladder with air and force the air through the filter. Allow 24 hours to dry and store in a cool dry place